# How to Configuration Device as a Single Purpose Application Device?

Tags: android

I have seen this in action in places like hostels/hotels:

How can you lock/restrict/configure an android device to only use an application, while having the following or most of them?

1. After every boot open and lock to a specific application.
2. Restrict specific hardware buttons, if any. (power button or all)
3. Lock device to use specific applications.

Is there anything "out of the box" provided by the SDK when building your applications? And if there is something like that what is the API support for that and how low does it get, API level wise?

Do you configure your device in a specific way? Is ther a documented pipeline for that?

I would prefer something official from google rather than 3rd party applications that do that.

Comment: did you check this https://developer.android.com/work/cosu or http://www.andreas-schrade.de/2015/02/16/android-tutorial-how-to-create-a-kiosk-mode-in-android/?

Comment: Actualy no i have been getting trash results from google search, might be the way i searched it, thanks looking into it. @Bartosz

Answer (score 0):

First of all Single Purpose application is supported after Android 5.0.

To lock the app on your device call a method startLockTask()  in your onCreate of launcher activity.

For detailed decription see this [doc](https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/gadgets-and-tech/news/facebook-artificial-intelligence-ai-chatbot-new-language-research-openai-google-a7869706.html).

Comment: That's a bad link

Answer (score 0):

firet it will suport in or after android 5.0

second lock app on your device for that creaate activity for luncer startLockTask(){}